# Android-betterpickers: Exclude hourly recurrence

Tags: java, android, recurrence, picker

Helo,

I've got a question.

I'm using RecurrencePickerDialogFragment like this:

```
final RecurrencePickerDialogFragment.OnRecurrenceSetListener recurrencelistener = new RecurrencePickerDialogFragment.OnRecurrenceSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRecurrenceSet(String rrule) {

            setRRule(rrule);

            newReccurenceListener();
        }
    };
    repeatrule.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            boolean sameday = timefrom.get(Calendar.YEAR) == timeto.get(Calendar.YEAR) &&
                    timefrom.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == timeto.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) &&
                    timefrom.get(Calendar.MONTH) == timeto.get(Calendar.MONTH);



            if (sameday == true) {
                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();

                bundle.putLong(RecurrencePickerDialogFragment.BUNDLE_START_TIME_MILLIS, time.getTimeInMillis());
                bundle.putString(RecurrencePickerDialogFragment.BUNDLE_TIME_ZONE, time.getTimeZone().getID());
                if (NewDate.this.rrule != null) {
                    bundle.putString(RecurrencePickerDialogFragment.BUNDLE_RRULE, NewDate.this.rrule);
                }

                RecurrencePickerDialogFragment rpd = (RecurrencePickerDialogFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(
                        "recurrencePickerDialogFragment");
                if (rpd != null) {
                    rpd.dismiss();
                }
                rpd = new RecurrencePickerDialogFragment();
                rpd.setArguments(bundle);
                rpd.setOnRecurrenceSetListener(recurrencelistener);
                rpd.show(fm, "recurrencePickerDialogFragment");


            } 
        }
    });
```

But I've got one problem:

How can I exclude hourly recurrence from RecurrencePickerDialogFragment?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNCqr.png)

Comment: What is repeatrule? You have posted a random code. Did you understand the tutorial from where you posted? If you did it won't be difficult to remove the Hourly option. These options are passed to an array. And then some switch case statements are used for each time interval. You need to modify the code accordingly. I read from here https://github.com/code-troopers/android-betterpickers/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/codetroopers/betterpickers/recurrencepicker/RecurrencePickerDialogFragment.java

Comment: repeatrule is current rrule.